# Shadowbox 3.0.3 reload parent when shadowboxed window gets closed

Tags: javascript, shadowbox

i want to know if there is a way to reload the parent page when you close the shadowbox. Basically i have a page , which lists all my categories. I use shadowbox to call the edit.php? page to do all my editing and i want to reload the parent page which called shadowbox in order for any changes made to be applied without the need for the user to refresh the parent page.

i've found this[ http://shadowbox.1309102.n2.nabble.com/Reload-parent-page-on-close-td4190962.html ] after googling , but in shadowbox.js(free version) i cannot find any of the related code mentioned in that post.

any ideas ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really simple, there is a onClose-event:

```
Shadowbox.init({onClose:function(){location.reload();}});
```